# Objectify transaction throws IllegalStateException

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, objectify

/!\ Sorry for this question. In fact, my error is to get an object after done getTxn().commit() :( /!\

I'm a beginner with Objectify and GAE. I dont understand why during a transaction I have this exception :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction with which this operation is associated is not active.

I use Objectify 3.1 and I have a class like this :

```
@Entity
public class A {
   @Id
   public Long m_id;

   @Parent
   public Key<B> m_key;

   public int m_foo;
}
```

I do this to get my object :

```
Key<B> key = new Key<B>(B.class, bId);
Query<A> query = ObjectifyService.beginTransaction().query(A.class).ancestor(key).<a class="ktg6us78hf8vdu7" href="#">filter</a>("m_foo =", foo);
return query.list().get(0);
```

When filter("m_foo =", foo) is called that always throws the exception above.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can always ask this on the Objectify groups list at:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/objectify-appengine

Comment: Thank you. I add [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/objectify-appengine/jMcmf3PPubI)